# Run a powershell script in a storage account using Terraform when building an azure vm

Tags: terraform

I am attempting to write terraform code which when the VM is being created the code will reach out to a storage account and run a powershell script.  there seems to be some solutions to my answer but all the solutions I have found are using a public blob access.  I have to disable enable blob public access. Below is my terraform code and error

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "powershell" {
  count = length(var.instances)
  name = "runpowershell"
  virtual_machine_id = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm.*.id[count.index]
    depends_on           = [azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm]
    publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
    type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
    type_handler_version = "1.9"
settings             = <<SETTINGS
      {
          "fileUris": ["https://test.blob.core.windows.net/scripts/deployment.ps1"],
          "commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file deployment.ps1"
                
      }
  SETTINGS
```

[image]

I changed the code to

```
``{
          "fileUris": ["https://test.blob.core.windows.net/scripts/deployment.ps1"]                          
      }
  SETTINGS
  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
       {
           "storageAccountKey": "Vg/4BBah3......ASt2sbGww==",
            "storageAccountName": "test",
            "commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File deployment.ps1"
       }
   PROTECTED_SETTINGS
   }
```

now i get the message - which reads Forbidden now not conflict  - I checked the key and it is correct
Error: Code="VMExtensionProvisioningError" Message="VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'runpowershell'. Error message: "Failed to download all specified files. Exiting. Error Message: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."\r\n\r\nMore information on troubleshooting is available at https://aka.ms/VMExtensionCSEWindowsTroubleshoot "

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found my answer.  In the code I pasted I changed the name of the actual storage account.  In my code for fileurs I had the correct name but for storage account in protected settings I spelled the account wrong.  Once I fixed that...it all worked.